# Logging into SMBclient works when server is running as a normal process, but not when it runs as a systemd service

Tags: node.js, bash, smb

I am using smbclient to update a database. There is a button on my website which pings my node server to run a bash script which handles this. When I run node as a systemd service, I get an NT_STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE error. Runnig node from the command line, however, this works fine.

I am running CENTOS 7, Node v12.6.0, and smbclient v4.8.3.

This is the command from the bash script

`eval "smbclient $SHARE $PSWD -u $USER -W=$WRKGRP -c dir" >> $LOGFILE`

This is the command from the node server

`shell.exec(__dirname + '/scripts/web_update.sh')`

Comment: Is there any possibility that the environment variables could be different under systemd?

Comment: @RossPresser I guess it's possible though I don't know which ones would make a difference

Comment: Try `strings /proc/<pid>/environ` for both variants. Maybe redirect each into a file and use `diff` to compare those.

Comment: I'm particularly thinking that `$USER` might be defined by the systemd environment. Of course if you're defining it in the script then that's not a factor.